# Publishing app for production React Native

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-ios, expo

I have been developing an app using React Native (detached from expo) but I fail to understand few things when it comes to publish the app for production.

From what I understand my native code which for example lives inside .apk( when building from android studio) and the javascript code which is running somewhere on the cloud are collaborating to each other so the app function properly, so basically you have two things to take care.

When I use **expo publish** command I can see that something is being uploaded somewhere (my javascript code along with assets) probably into amazon cloud service, I don't understand the idea behind this, what if one day those amazon links are not available, what would happen with my app? would it stop working?

I would really appreciate if someone can explain how this thing really works, is it possible that I don't rely on those bundleUrl that I see from the manifest after app published, I mean can I have those running into my server so I have full control of it, if so how much work this will raise?

Also what if one day Expo is un available so the service is shutdown, this things are wondering me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can confirm here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#content that your Javascript code is for real within your apk file.

Comment: so does this mean that yes there is a javascript somewhere on cloud that is serving for my apk? if so, do u have any idea that we can have that javascript hosting on our server?

Comment: I can't confirm that since I am not React Native developer. But I think you all got it wrong. If I get your question correctly your Javascript code that you wrote in your React Native app is stored within apk. Javascript is native language to both Android and iOS. I can't confirm for UWP.

Comment: this part I want to know for sure, if the javascript is store within the .apk, if so then why do I have to publish using comand expo publish everytime I make new changes into javascript? I mean cant I rebuild the app and republish it the new apk?

Comment: React Native is not a web view app so it is not accessible trough some url/link.
From what I know Expo is only online apk builder for React Native.
It is a framework for React Native that provides you their stuff that you can use in React Native projects. As I said, I am not React Native developer so I don't know if they have actual extensions for some IDE so you don't need to build apk online.

Can you explain why did you chose React Native in a first place?
It is a weird choice for a development of mobile app since it has a lot of limitations.

Comment: initially i choosed bc i have to write once and run multiple platforms, main reason.  also you can embed native code if u want in a detached app... but I am failing to understand that part where the javascript bundle is living when I am publishing using expo publish. I see some amazon url so basically looks like my native code lives inside .apk and the javascript code into amazon service which is like two part of it and makes it not reliable from my pov!

Comment: I believe that is only a link to Expo build.
Keep doing it if you find it entertaining, but chosing React Native can be a bad thing in the future if you need to do something that is not covered by it.
There are better choices like Java (even tho Java is not supported on iOS) or Xamarin Native. Xamarin Native is much more stable and powerfull. Xamarin also supports using native stuff from Java.

Comment: thou I am not here to compare different platforms, but React Native detached you can mix with native code so you can basically achieve whatever u want and u dont feel like limited at all!  for someone who knows javascript can write native app, isnt that cool? You use javascript to call native functions of each platform!

Comment: I know. Sorry if I am a little bit off topic, but I hope I gave you a clue about Expo.

Comment: but you are not so sure what you are saying, so that does not really help on this case as you have to give some explanation about this in order to have a right answer!

Comment: I am talking based on what official documentations are saying (both ReactNative and Expo documentations).

Comment: so u saying that  Javascript code that you wrote in your React Native app is stored within apk, can you show me this part on documentation?

Comment: Yes I am saying that. You can confirm that here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#content where it is saying that Javascript is within apk.

Comment: I think this is right, how I missed it! thanks now I can say that this is safe :) also you can structure your answer and I can accept it!

Comment: now it makes more sense why I have to use expo publish command, just so i dont have to re-build the .apk each time I make changes into javascript part and have to need to re-install the app to see new changes....

Comment: Now you get it :) Glad I could be of some help to you. I will structure my answer.